# Jquery: Traverse a table to find the occurance of a value and chage the row's css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table structure as:

```
 <table id="table1">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Task</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>task 1</td>
                    <td>SUC</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>task 2</td>
                    <td>SUC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>task 3</td>
                    <td>ERR</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>task 4</td>
                    <td>ERR</td>
                </tr>
```

I want to check for the status of all task and if status is **ERR** then I must change that row's CSS. For that I have a jquery like this:

```
$('#table1 td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());

    if ($(this).html() == 'ERR') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ffe83d');
    }
```

It just changes the css of that particular cell of columun *Status* .

I want to change the css of whole row with status **ERR**.
I had tried things like

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', '#59f763');
```

Comment: .parent() is working for me, see the fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/8aym1uzc/

Answer (score 1):

Try this : use `closest('tr')`

```
$('#table1 td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());

    if ($(this).html() == 'ERR') {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#ffe83d');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use **[contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** in jquery

```
$("#table1 td:contains('ERR')").parent().css('background-color', '#59f763');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheswaran/rwuoonb5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the td with html "ERR" and then get its parent tr using parent() ass apply css to it.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bfva8jLf/)

```
$('#table1 td').filter(function(){
   return $(this).html() == "ERR";
}).parent().css('background-color', '#59f763');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', '#59f763');
```

to this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').css('background-color', '#59f763');
```